# Change class of item when scrolled to

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I have a nav set up that when a link is clicked, the page scrolls down to the corresponding item in a list, changing the class of the link when the item is reached.

```
<nav> 
<a href="#one" class="anchorLink">one</a> 
<a href="#two" class="anchorLink">two</a> </nav>


 <ul>
  <li id="one"></li>
  <li id="two"></li> 
 </ul>
```

Here is a rather crude example

http://jsfiddle.net/FSk5Q/1/

I would also like to change the background colour of the item once it is reached (preferably fading to a new colour), and then restore it's original class when another item is scrolled to, then changing the next item's class.

I need this to happen when clicked to AND scrolled to, so the :target option is not really ideal.

Many thanks for an advice. Not too good in the js department.

Comment: Check this out: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this can at least get you started.  What I have done is check that the offset top is less than the document's scroll top (you could also do something like if it's within X number of pixels).

The color fading can be done with CSS3 transitions.

```
$(document).on('scroll', function () {
    $("li").each(function () {
        if ($(this).offset().top <= $(document).scrollTop()) {
            $("li").removeClass('highlight');
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass('highlight');
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FSk5Q/6/

Comment: Thanks so much, this is very close to what I need. How would I make the class change when the item reaches the top, at the moment it seems to have to pass the top before it changes.

Comment: @xhadf I think use `<=` to compare.  You can also do it when it is *close* to the top; something like `<= $(document).scrollTop() + 10`

Answer (score 0):

I did a fixed version based on *Explosion Pills*' one. Hope it's what you wanted.

```
$(document).on('scroll', function ()
{
    $("nav a").removeClass('highlight'); // reset all menu items
    temp = $();
    $("li").each(function (i) // for each content blcok (you schould give them a class)
    { 
        if ($(this).offset().top <= $(document).scrollTop()) // if it's position is above/at the page top
        {
            temp = $("nav a:nth-child("+(i+1)+")");
        }
    });
    temp.addClass('highlight');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/maxmeuten/FSk5Q/8/